# Pass variable to a collection filter function

Tags: laravel

I have the following function:

```php
function permissions_filter($id, $filter)
    {
        return User::where('id', $id)->first()->getAllPermissions()->pluck('name')->filter(function ($item) {
            return str_contains($item, $filter) == true;
        })->values();
    }
```

Where i need to pass `$filter` to the function inside the filter, however just adding it to `function ($item, $filter)` behaves as separating the key and value from the item being iterated (same as how `foreach ($item as $k=>$v)` works). How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters when writing a callback function in php (Laravel 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300510/passing-parameters-when-writing-a-callback-function-in-php-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `use($filter)`. I've also change `where('id', $id)->first()` to `find($id)`.

```php
function permissions_filter($id, $filter) {
    return User::find($id)
        ->getAllPermissions()
        ->pluck('name')
        ->filter(function ($item) use ($filter) {
            return str_contains($item, $filter) == true;
        })
        ->values();
}
```